# What character can "□" [fei3] meaning 呕吐 be?

Tags: characters, character-identification

I've got this entry from 《广安方言与民俗词典》which goes as follows:

> □
>
> fei3
>
> 指呕吐。例：他中午吃醉酒了，fei3了一地。

□ is as [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%96%A1) states:

> Used as a placeholder for an unknown hanzi.

There's a good chance though that this character *word* does have an actual representational character.

I've not been able to find any MSM *fei* readings that mean to throw up/to barf, etc.

**Notes**: *fei3* is equivalent to [fei⁵³] - so almost the same as fei4 in MSM.

Any ideas on what it can be?

---

My leaning at the moment is that *fei3* is actually a contraction (合音) of something like *发呕* or *发哕* - not that I have any proof for it but it seems to be the most likely at the moment.

Comment: Does《广安方言与民俗词典》have a radical lookup or something similar, such that you can back-reference the page number for which this entry appears?

Comment: @droooze They claim there is no character for this word. But, I'm thinking that there might be a fitting one that they haven't included.

Comment: Did you see this in an electronic version or paper book?

Comment: @fefe The paper edition is the same as the electronic version, I've checked both. There might not be an actual character at all, it is a topolect that we're talking about after all. Their editors obviously believe that there is no character, I'm proposing that there might in fact be a suitable character though, because often times there *is*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking it could be a word similar to 淝 in Cantonese.

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/8979/

> 淝
>   fe4 fei4 jyutping
>   fei2 pinyin
>   [粵] fe4 - Cantonese only
>   [1] [v] spray/sprinkle (water)
>   [2] [v] shoot; gun down
>   [粵] fei4 [國] fei2
>   [n] name of a river in Anhui province, famous in Chinese history for Battle of Fei River (AD 383)

Examples of usage:
淝到周圍都係
淝啲成身濕

Comment: Very well could be.